# Can we observe galaxies after their recession velocity exceeds the speed of light?

Tags: expansion, observable-universe, hubble-constant

It doesn't make sense to me that light could ever reach us from a galaxy moving away from us faster than the speed of light.  But [this video](https://youtu.be/q67vH0SKahU?t=453) says that it can happen.  Is this true?  Could someone explain how it is possible?

Comment: Your title didn't match your question. I've edited the title to make it consistent with what you're asking.

Comment: @Jim421616 I understand how galaxies outside the Hubble Sphere can recede from us at faster than the speed of light due to the Universe expansion.  I just don't understand if and how light from those galaxies can then reach us.  I am going to rollback your title edit.

Comment: You're quite welcome to roll back the edit, but my point was that the title asks one question, and the body asks another question. Better to have the title as a summary, and put both questions in the body. Better yet, post two separate questions.

Comment: Perhaps this question will help...https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107748/how-are-galaxies-receding-faster-than-light-visible-to-observers

Comment: Yes, we can most definitely see galaxies with recession speeds exceeding the speed of light. See [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19910/5264).

Comment: @pela Yes, the answer you linked is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I think that may make this question a duplicate.  Perhaps I should close it.